# Usando Ajax, deseo que se me despliegue una lista donde la condicion esta entre 3 valores

Tags: php, ajax

Por favor quien me podría decir donce esta el error? Deseo que se me despliegue una lista consulta partiendo de 3 valores introducidos: id_inmueble entre 2 fechas.

**El error que muestra es:**

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$inmueble' in 'where clause' in /homepages/9/d795872911/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Trinitarias/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/dao/adminDAO.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/9/d795872911/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Trinitarias/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/dao/adminDAO.php(57): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /homepages/9/d795872911/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Trinitarias/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/dao/busca_por_fecha.php(37): adminDAO->buscarAllBitacoraFecha('2020-03-17', '2020-04-03', 'II.1-C') #2 {main} thrown in /homepages/9/d795872911/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Trinitarias/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/dao/adminDAO.php on line 57

**Aquí el código:**

```
 <?php
                      $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                      $path .= "/conexion_inst.php";
                      require($path); 
                      $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select id, id_inmueble, propietario from inmuebles order by id");
                     ?>
                     <br>
                     <div class="form-group col-md-2">      

                      <div class="col">
                      <label for="option">Inmueble:</label> 
                      <select class="form-control col-md-4" name="bd-inmueble" id="bd-inmueble">
                          <?php while($datosinmueble=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){?> 
                             <option value="<?php echo $datosinmueble['id_inmueble']?>"> <?php 
                             echo $datosinmueble['id_inmueble'] . ' (' . $datosinmueble['propietario'] . ')';
                             ?>

                             </option>
                            <?php 
                            }

                            ?>
                       </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                            <!-- RANGO DE FECHAS A BUSCAR Y EXPORTAR -->
                            <label style="font-weight: normal;">Desde: <input class="form-control" type="date" id="bd-desde"/></label>
                            <label style="font-weight: normal;">Hasta: <input class="form-control" type="date" id="bd-hasta"/></label>
                            <button id="rango_fecha" class="btn-sm btn-primary">Buscar</button>
                            <!-- BOTON PARA EXPORTAR EL RANGO DE FECHAS -->
                            <a onClick="javascript:reportePDF();" class="btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding: 8px 15px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;">Exportar PDF<span><img src='/exportar_pdf/cargando.gif' class="cargando hide"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                <div class="row">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5">Fila</th>
                        <th width="20">En Banco</th>
                        <th width="20">Inmueble</th>
                        <th width="20">Monto</th>
                        <th width="20">Referencia</th>
                        <th width="60">Observaciones</th>
                        <th width="6">Banco</th>
                        <th width="20">Tipo</th>
                        <th width="20">Documento</th>
                        <th width="20">Saldo Inmueble</th>
                        <th width="20">Procesado</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!-- CONTENEDOR DONDE SE IMPRIMEN LA CONSULTA POR FECHAS -->
                    <tbody id="actualizar">
                        <?php include('/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/includes/imprimir_bitacora.php'); ?>
                    </tbody>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="ver-pdf" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
            <h2 class="text-center">Reporte Generado</h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

         <div id="view_pdf"></div>
            <a id="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function busca_por_fecha(){    
    $('#rango_fecha','#bd-inmueble').on('click',function(){
        var desde = $('#bd-desde').val();
        var hasta = $('#bd-hasta').val();
        var inmueble = $('#bd-inmueble').val();
        var url = '/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/dao/busca_por_fecha.php';
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:'desde='+desde+'&hasta='+hasta+'&inmueble='+inmueble,
        success: function(datos){
            $('#actualizar').html(datos);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
})();
```

Y el codigo del archivo buscaporfecha.php y adminDAO.php:

**adminDAO.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logueado"])){

        header("location: ../form/login.php");

    }

?>


<?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/exportar_pdf/db/accesoDB.php";
   require_once($path);

    //require_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/db/accesoDB.php';
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Lima");

    function fechaNormal($fecha){
        $nfecha = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fecha));
        return $nfecha;
    }

    class adminDAO{

        public function allBitacora(){
            try{
                $pdo = AccesoDB::getConnectionPDO();

                $sql='SELECT id, fec_comp, id_inmueble, monto_comp, num_comp, observaciones, cod_banco, tipo_doc, num_doc, saldo_inmueble, fec_proc from pagos_por_aprobar ORDER BY id DESC';

                //$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bitacora ORDER BY id DESC';

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();

                $return = $stmt->fetchAll();
                return $return;

            } catch (Exception $e){
                throw $e;
            }   
        }

        public function buscarAllBitacoraFecha($desde,$hasta,$inmueble){
            try{
                $pdo = AccesoDB::getConnectionPDO();

                $sql='SELECT id, fec_comp, id_inmueble, monto_comp, num_comp, observaciones, cod_banco, num_doc, tipo_doc, saldo_inmueble, fec_proc from pagos_por_aprobar where ((fec_proc BETWEEN "'.$desde.'" AND "'.$hasta.'") and (id_inmueble=$inmueble)) ORDER BY id DESC';

                //$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bitacora WHERE fecha BETWEEN "'.$desde.'" AND "'.$hasta.'" ORDER BY id DESC';

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();

                $return = $stmt->fetchAll();
                return $return;

            } catch (Exception $e){
                throw $e;
            }   
        }

    }

?>
```

**buscaporfecha.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logueado"])){

        header("location:../form/login.php");

    }

?>


<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/dao/adminDAO.php";
require_once($path);

$impr = new adminDAO();


//EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA DE BUSQUEDA
if($_POST['desde']==false || $_POST['hasta']==false){
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/includes/imprimir_bitacora.php";
    include($path);

    //include dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/exportar_pdf/includes/imprimir_bitacora.php';
}else{
    $desde = $_POST['desde'];
    $hasta = $_POST['hasta'];
    $inmueble = $_POST['inmueble'];

    //EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA DE BUSQUEDA

    $datos = $impr->buscarAllBitacoraFecha($desde,$hasta,$inmueble);

?>
<?php 
    if(count($datos)>0){ 
    for($x=0; $x<count($datos); $x++){
?>
if ($datos[$x]['id_inmueble']=$inmueble){
<tr>
    <td><?php  $x; $l = $x+1; echo $l; ?></td>
    $id_inmueble = $datos[$x]['id_inmueble'];
    $monto_comp = $datos[$x]['monto_comp'];
    $num_comp = $datos[$x]['num_comp'];
    $observaciones = $datos[$x]['observaciones'];
    $cod_banco = $datos[$x]['cod_banco'];
    $num_doc = $datos[$x]['num_doc'];
    $tipo_doc = $datos[$x]['tipo_doc'];
    $saldo_inmueble = $datos[$x]['saldo_inmueble'];


    <td><?php echo fechaNormal($datos[$x]['fec_comp']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $datos[$x]['id_inmueble']; ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $datos[$x]['monto_comp']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $datos[$x]['num_comp']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $datos[$x]['observaciones']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $datos[$x]['cod_banco']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $datos[$x]['tipo_doc']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $datos[$x]['num_doc']; ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $datos[$x]['saldo_inmueble']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo fechaNormal($datos[$x]['fec_proc']); ?></td>
</tr>
}
<?php
    }
    }else{
?>
    <tr class="odd"><td valign="top" colspan="8" class="dataTables_empty">No hay datos disponibles en la tabla</td></tr>
<?php
    }
}           
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

     window.print();



  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si, en el siguiente archivo (adminDAO.php)  hago la consulta:

Answer (score 0):

El código que has puesto no es el que contiene el error.
Si lees el error verás que la columna $inmueble (nótese el signo $) no existe. En algún lado estás haciendo una censulta que contiene algo similar a:
... WHERE $inmueble= ...

Comment: Hola Carlos, agregue el codigo de dos archivos: en uno de ellos hago la consulta.

Comment: Has puesto id_inmueble=$inmueble
Debes poner '.$variable.' para que se lea como tal.

Ademas estás permitiendo al usuario enviar información sin validar por lo que en cualquier momento alguien podría, entre otras cosas, borrar tu base de datos.
Usa intval para convertir cualquier dato aportado por el usuario en un número integro y htmlspecialchas para texto que quieras volver a mostrar.
También debes usar $pdo->prepare() y pasar las variables por $db->bindParam() o $db->bindValue()

Comment: listo. me funcionó. Ahora tengo otro problema. Me dice que no estan definidas las variables. Quiza estoy haciendo mal el llamado a la funcion

Comment: No soy adivino para saber que error te da. ¿Es posible que hayas entendido que debias poner literalmente '.$variable.' en vez de '.$inmueble.'?

Comment: si. eso lo coloqué. Perdon. Simplemente no muestra nada, solamente los input del form